# Count forward and check date forward

Tags: c#

this is how I would like that to build up such that it has the date today d 2 / 23-2015 and so it goes 30 days ahead of the date, which means it will be d 22.02.2015,

I've tried to do like this:

```
string datoTid = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

    DateTime equalsDato = datoTid.AddDays(1 * 30);

    string slutdato = equalsDato.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Comment: Why do you try to add days to a string? Instead add them to the `DateTime` you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
string slutdato = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1 * 30).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what your asking, I believe your intent is to take the current date and added thirty days.  Which would be:

```
var date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
```

This would provide a type of `DateTime`.  Then you can create a `string` representation of the designated `DateTime`. (In your desired format)

```
date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
```

This would provide your modification for the format, while simply applying the designated date ahead.